# Unable to Scroll In Arch Virtual Machine Running Gnome Shell

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, gnome, arch-linux, windows-10-preview

In my Arch VM (on VirtualBox), I cannot scroll in any program.

System:

- Windows 10 with VirtualBox v4.3.20, r96997
- Razor Deathadder Chroma mouse
- The VM is Arch Linux 64-bit, running gnome-shell and xorg.

What I've tried:

- Changed the chipset that VirtualBox is using
- Switched mice, changed the pointing device type that it used
- Changed settings around with the VM
- Attempted to attach the mouse device to the VM (was not a good idea)
- Disabled mouse integration
- I've created an entirely new VM (running the same OS), which didn't do much good

I used an xorg program that showed the events that were being triggered, and it didn't seem that scrolling was one of the events that were being triggered.

Comment: Since there ought to be a way to do this, you just haven't tried the right thing yet.  For someone to figure out what you haven't tried that might work, they need to know exactly what you have tried.  "I've done everything I possibly can", and "and everything else I could possibly think of" implies that you tried things in addition to the ones you mentioned.  Can you elaborate?  What settings have you tried?  Is this a simple mouse that would use the default driver?

Comment: @fixer1234 I updated the question.